# Mongodb Native Query

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

My Data from Mongodb

```
{
 "_id" : ObjectId("57d718ddd4c618cbf04772d6"),
 "_class" : "io.core.entity.Layer",
 "name" : "u2",
 "layerMembers" : [ 
     {
         "permission" : "OWNER",
         "user" : {
             "_id" : ObjectId("57d440c3d4c60e2f13553216"),
             "nameSurname" : "User 2",
             "email" : "user2@email.com"
         },
         "isOwner" : true
     }, 
     {
         "permission" : "EDIT",
         "user" : {
             "_id" : ObjectId("57d44050d4c62bfdc8a9fd30"),
             "nameSurname" : "User 1",
             "email" : "user@email.com"
     },
        "isOwner" : false
    }
 ]
}
```

My queries;

```
db.getCollection('layer').find({$and: [{"layerMembers.user._id":     
ObjectId("57d440c3d4c60e2f13553216"), "layerMembers.permission":    
"EDIT"}]})

db.getCollection('layer').find({$and: [{"layerMembers.user._id": 
ObjectId("57d440c3d4c60e2f13553216"), "layerMembers.isOwner":    
false}]})
```

These queries, both of them found my data, but in my opinion, it should not get this data. Because query is 'AND' query and when the user id equals "57d440c3d4c60e2f13553216", permission is "OWNER" and "layerMembers.isOwner" is true.

And also this query can find my data.

```
db.getCollection('layer').find({"layerMembers.user._id": 
ObjectId("57d440c3d4c60e2f13553216"), "layerMembers.isOwner": false})
```

What is the missing part ?

Answer (score 0):

You should use $elemMatch (https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/elemMatch/) if you want to only return a document where you are trying to match multiple fields within a nested array.

something like:

```
{ 
  "layerMembers": 
    "$elemMatch": {
       "user._id": ObjectId("57d440c3d4c60e2f13553216"),
       "permission": "EDIT"
     }
}
```

Comment: Thanks @mattetre, This is what i want.